# One of the views goes under the other view when doing transform animation with CATransform3DIdentity, even if I use autoreverses

Tags: ios, swift

I have reproduced the animation example so it is possible to just copy paste this to see the effect. What I would like is to do the animation on the redview, but I would want it to continue to appear above the green view after the animation, but it seems to go under it after the animation even if I set autoreverses = true. I tried putting redview.transform = .identity in the completion block but it didn't help.

```
import UIKit

class AnimationTest: UIViewController {
    
    let greenView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .green
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()
    
    let redView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        
        view.addSubview(greenView)
        greenView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 150).isActive = true
        greenView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
        greenView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -50).isActive = true
        greenView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -150).isActive = true
        
        view.addSubview(redView)
        redView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
        redView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true
        redView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -40).isActive = true
        redView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -100).isActive = true
    
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap))
        redView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }
    
    @objc func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        var transform = CATransform3DIdentity
        let angle: CGFloat = 0.1
        transform.m34 = -1.0 / 500.0 // [500]: Smaller -> Closer to the 'camera', more distorted
        transform     = CATransform3DRotate(transform, angle, 0, 1, 0)
        let duration = 0.1
        let translationAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform")
        translationAnimation.toValue = transform
        translationAnimation.duration = duration
        translationAnimation.fillMode = .forwards
        translationAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeOut)
        translationAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        translationAnimation.autoreverses = true
        CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
        }
        redView.layer.add(translationAnimation, forKey: "translation")
        CATransaction.commit()
        
    }
    
}
```

EDIT:

Also I have another scenario where I add the view into the keywindow because I want it to appear above tab bars. But now the animation goes into the keywindow. How can I make the same animation without going into the keywindow.

```
import UIKit

class AnimationTest: UIViewController {
    
    let redView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .white

    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        guard let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow else { return }
        let y = 16 + 10 + 30 + window.safeAreaInsets.top
        let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 8 - 8
        let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height - window.safeAreaInsets.top - window.safeAreaInsets.bottom - 16 - 10 - 30 - 4 - 50
        redView.frame = CGRect(x: 8, y: y, width: width, height: height)
        window.addSubview(redView)

        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap))
        redView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }
    
    @objc func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        var transform = CATransform3DIdentity
        let angle: CGFloat = 0.1
        transform.m34 = -1.0 / 500.0 // [500]: Smaller -> Closer to the 'camera', more distorted
        transform     = CATransform3DRotate(transform, angle, 0, 1, 0)
        let duration = 0.1
        let translationAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform")
        translationAnimation.fromValue = CATransform3DIdentity
        translationAnimation.toValue = transform
        translationAnimation.duration = duration
        translationAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeOut)
        translationAnimation.autoreverses = true
        CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {

        }
        redView.layer.add(translationAnimation, forKey: "translation") // Key doesn't matter, just call it translation.
        CATransaction.commit()
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to:

1. Set the `fromValue` to `CATransform3DIdentity`
2. Remove `translationAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false`

I also cleaned up some of your other code. You don't need the `setCompletionBlock` or `CATransaction` at all. You also don't need `fillMode`.

```
@objc func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    var transform = CATransform3DIdentity
    let angle: CGFloat = 0.1
    transform.m34 = -1.0 / 500.0 // [500]: Smaller -> Closer to the 'camera', more distorted
    transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, angle, 0, 1, 0)
    
    let duration = 0.5
    let translationAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform")
    translationAnimation.fromValue = CATransform3DIdentity /// here!
    translationAnimation.toValue = transform
    translationAnimation.duration = duration
    translationAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeOut)
    translationAnimation.autoreverses = true
    
    redView.layer.add(translationAnimation, forKey: "transformKey")
}
```

| Before | After |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Green view goes over red view after animation is done] | [image: Green view remains under red view after animation is done] |

### Edit: Red view sinks under window

You will need to adjust the layer's z position to be higher.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    guard let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow else { return }
    let y = 16 + 10 + 30 + window.safeAreaInsets.top
    let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 8 - 8
    let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height - window.safeAreaInsets.top - window.safeAreaInsets.bottom - 16 - 10 - 30 - 4 - 50
    redView.frame = CGRect(x: 8, y: y, width: width, height: height)
    window.addSubview(redView)

    redView.layer.zPosition = 100 /// here!
    
    
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap))
    redView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}
```

| 0 (Default) | 10 | 100 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image: Right side of red view disappears into the window while left rotates in 3D perfectly] | [image: Right side of the red view is fine at first, but after a bit starts to disappear into the window. Left side is fine] | [image: Right side of view does not disappear into the window. The 3D rotate effect is perfect.] |
| Half is completely obscured | Part of the view sinks | Completely fine |

Comment: Thank you for the help! Do you know what I can do with the second problem? I posted it as edit in the original post. Trying to add the redview into the keywindow so that it appears above tab bars etc, but then it goes into the screen and the animation does not appear correct because it goes into the keywindow. Do you know what I could do here?

Comment: @Alex Sure, I'll take a look

Comment: Thanks, did you manage to have a look? ^^

Comment: @Alex yes, sorry, I went to bed. Just add a `redView.layer.zPosition = 100` to make the layer's z position higher, so it won't sink under the window.